# Ammeter with 2 voltage sources without superposition

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, current-measurement

I'm studying for the exam of this very basic circuit analysis class that I'm taking, and there is this particular problem in the textbook:

[image]

You are supposed to solve this without using the superposition technique. However, no matter what I have tried, I could never get the same result that they provided. If anyone could explain the steps to solving this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: First, you need to show us your attempt.

Comment: Hint: what is the voltage drop across an ideal ammeter?

Comment: Use @Transistor's hint and solve for the current in *each* R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework without an attempt.

Comment: @Transistor There is no voltage drop, it basically acts as a wire in this case.

Comment: @hkovesdi: OK. So what's the voltage across the 5 Ω resistor?

Comment: My initial approach was to find the current flowing through each resistor using KVL. I made 3 loops, so on the top right resistor i got 4 amps, the bottom one 3 amps, and on the left 1.2 amps. Is this the correct approach? Am i allowed to make 3 loops or am i missing something?

Comment: Hmm the bottom left one might actually be 3.6 amps, not 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I have actually managed to solve it.
I of R2ohm is 3amps
I of R3ohm is 4amps
I of R5ohm is 3.6amps
Writing down a KVL on the top right node we get -7.6 amps of current flowing through the 12V source, then another KVL at the node left to the ammeter we actually get the -10.6 amps.

Comment: Good. You solved it yourself. You can mark this answer correct to show the problem is solved. (You may have to wait a day.) +1.